# Showing XML in browser efficiently

Tags: javascript, angular, xml, angular10

I have a requirement where I need to show XML I receive in browser. I am working with angular 10. So what I have done already is when I receive any XML string, I try to replace all HTML entities so that DOMParser does not treat them as undefined entity. Then I parsed that XML using a DOMParser and  used my own logic(retrieving all necessary values from a node and then its children in depth-first manner) to convert parsed XML to JSON and then used recursive templates to show them. It all works fine when the size of file is small around 200 to 300 KB but unfortunately I have to load files around 9 MB but the size can grow till 50 MB. My angular application becomes unresponsive, when I tried to load files of size over 2 MB, and soon my browser as well.
Any ideas on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you seem to be writing an awful lot of cumbersome code to do what could be done much more easily with a bit of simple XSLT. But handling 50Mb of XML in the browser is going to perform badly with any technology. You need to split it into smaller chunks on the server side, and only fetch chunks on demand.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I too believe loading in chunks is the best option for handling large XMLs. Also, I am not good with XSLT, but aren't they used to convert XML to another type(XML, HTML), but here I just want to use the same XML, I need to show dom tree type view of XML, which can expand and collapse, colored tags and attributes, just like any browser opening XML.

Comment: There are various ways you could tackle this task in XSLT to save yourself a lot of Javascript coding -- with the interactive XSLT extensions in Saxon-JS you could do it entirely in XSLT. But that's up to you, and isn't central to the problem you're facing with document size.